# How to redirect to a record page?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, page-layout, pageblocksection

I have a custom VF page in a section in the Lead layout.

The page is showing a table with specific information.
[image]

When I clink on the link I expected to see an account record page.

The link is not a tag in the VF page.

What happens instead is the account record is displayed inside the section.

[image]

How to avoid the account record displayed in the Lead section.

When click on the link, how to redirect to the account record page?

Comment: Can you add the custom link code as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set attribute `target="_top"`

```
<apex:outputLink value="https://www.salesforce.com" target="_top" id="theLink">www.salesforce.com</apex:outputLink>
```